# How to name a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that is executed by a console application (VB using MS Visual Studio 2013) by passing in 2 parameters.  The code for the stored procedure is here:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[OptimiserReads_getMaxValue]
   @ReadDate datetime,
   @tagname nvarchar(50)
AS
Begin 
   declare @first float
   declare @second float

   set @first = '265'
   set @second = (select value
                  from RawHistorianData
                  where interval = @readdate and tagname = @tagname) 

   Select 
       CASE when @first > @second then @first else @second end
end
```

Basically it should result in a result of either `@first` or the result of `@second`.  If I execute the procedure in SQL Server Management Studio I get the required result.

In the console app I don't know how to name the result due to the `CASE` statement. How do I give the result a name in SQL ie something like

```
Select CASE (when @first > @second then @first else @second) as value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you mentioned in your questions, all you need to do is to add alias for your case statement.

The format is as follows.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @first > @second THEN @first
            ELSE @second
       END AS BiggerValue
```

Aliases can be used for columns, tables, joins, sub-queries and etc.

Format is always `'SomeObject' as 'Alias'`

For example:

- Table : `SELECT t.* from MyTable as t`
- Column: `SELECT FirstName as FN from MyTable`
- Sub-Query `SELECT * FROM (SELECT Name FROM MyTable) as SubQuery`

Answer (score 3):

```
Select CASE when @first > @second then @first else @second end as columnname
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select CASE when @first > @second then @first else @second end  as value
```